# What hardware do I need to start writing, compiling and running my own kernal? Do I need to buy a new machine like a raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, hardware

I am a student hoping to learn about how an operating systems works. After doing a bit of research I have decided I want to try to write my own kernal in C or C++.

I will also most likely be following along with [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide - by Peter Jay Salzman, Michael Burian and Ori Pomerantz.](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/) (Let me know if there is a better resource I should be looking at.)

I have access to my own personal windows computer and an ubuntu machine in college, neither of which I can afford to risk breaking.

I had this idea of a long term project of making a dummy spacecraft with a raspberry pi, and writing all the code for it. This kernal would be the first bit of it.

I looked at Linux From Scratch but that seemed to be more about just installing your own combination of programs that someone else has written, which doesn't interest me. What I want to do is write my own thread scheduler / memory manager etc and deal with all the headaches that that cause. (However I might want to make my kernal work with LFS later though.)

**My question:**

Basically, what I was hoping to find out is, what is the minimum I need to get started in terms of hardware to start writing, compiling and running my own kernal? Do I need to buy a new dedicated machine like a raspberry pi, or can I write / compile / run it on my own laptop?

Thanks very much.

Comment: A smaller simpler processor is probably a better choice than an RPi, because you don't have hardware debug access to the RPi and, probably more importantly, no developer documentation for the Broadcom chip on the RPi.  Unfortunately, systems with proper debuggers are either very low capacity (you won't be writing a dynamic allocator on a microcontroller with 4kB RAM, for example) or expensive, (or both).  The most promising result I found with a quick search was the [Hachiko dev board carrying a Renesas ARM processor](http://architechboards.org/product/hachiko-board).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a virtual machine such as QEmu, Bochs or VirtualBox to run and debug your kernel without risking ti ruin your computer. All you need to compile is any standard c/c++ compiler and an assembler.

Also, I suggest you to have a look at the [OSDev wiki website](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page), where they have lots of useful informations.

Remember that writing your own OS is probably the biggest challenge ever, so make sure you have all the tools and knowedge needed. I'm saying this beacause I tried to roll my own OS and I had to abandon it with a non working keyboard driver...

Anyway, as language I suggest C++ and not C because classes are a really useful tool in programming.

Comment: Hi dp_1, thanks very much for the answer, I'll definitely look into that, a VM sounds like a good solution to get started with, I really want to get started while I have the motivation and momentum up haha. Thanks!